# Creating string array from a delimited string.

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of urls, example `"domain.com/url1, domain.com/url2 etc"`. Sometimes they are comma, tab, or pipe delimited. What I'd like to do is split them up in a string array and automatically handle any potential use case. Does anybody know of a good way to handle this?

I started with something like this, but it doesn't function correctly nor does it handle all use cases.

```
Collection<String> newUrls = Arrays.asList(photoHolder.getPhotoURLs().replaceAll("\\|", ",").replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(","));
```

Comment: What do your delimiters have in common ? Do they all contain a space at the end ?

Comment: There is a photo field in a csv file and each csv file may very depending on the company producing it. They send me a list of photo urls, I just need to be able to handle all use cases. Sometimes there is spaces, sometimes there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should be possible with only using the `split` method and providing a regex that will match any of your delimiters.

```
Collection<String> newUrls = Arrays.asList(photoHolder.getPhotoURLs().split("\\t|\\||,"));
```

Comment: Will this remove any potential whitespace?

Comment: @CodeJunkie No it will not.  To do that, you would need to call `String#trim()` on each string instance.  Or you could come up with a more sophisticated REGEX that will match the whitespace and consider it to be part of the delimiter.

Comment: do you feel this might be the best solution then? photoHolder.getPhotoURLs().replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("\\t|\\||,")

Comment: @CodeJunkie I would probably not do that.  It's going to remove whitespace within values as well as whitespace around values.  Meaning, it will change something like "Hello World" to "HelloWorld," which is probably not what you want.  The programmatic solution (if you don't want to mess with the regex) would be to iterate over your new collection and call trim() on all your strings.

Comment: Perhaps, you can also try `[ ]*(?:\\t|\\||,)[ ]*` to avoid using trim later.

Answer (score 0):

You might use some "smart" regular expressions that are independent of the delimiter, but use the domain names (.com, .co.uk, IP addresses...) to separate the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have make some split methods to cover all the scenarios and finally put them in a one list. And the other case about the potential use case use a try catch and in the catch handle the exception because we cannot handle every scenario. Think this will be helpful somehow.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("domain.com/url1/what ever_the_url");
String protocol = uri.getScheme();
String server = uri.getAuthority();
String path = uri.getPath();
Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
String limit = uri.getQueryParameter("limit");
```

Try this also.